# display a photo in a list item undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, list, image, react-native, photo

I have a list of products, displayed using List Item from react-native-elements.
I want to add the product image as an 'icon' on the left of the product name.
I am having difficulty with an

> 'undefined is not an object'

when I call up the image.
I don't understand why an error is displayed, my array looks like this:

```
Object {
    "cost": 1099.99,
    "created_at": "2018-05-17T20:58:31Z",
    "custom_fields": Array [],
    "description": "",
    "family_id": 5,
    "id": 5,
    "incl_tax": 1,
    "is_visible": 1,
    "name": "Apple MacBook Air 13.3'' LED 128 Go SSD 8 Go",
    "photo": Object {
      "_1_": Object {
        "id": 1,
        "order": 1,
        "title_fr": "Apple-MacBook-Air-13-3-LED-128-Go-D-8-Go-RAM-Intel-Core-i5-bicoeur-a-1-8-Ghz-MQD32FN-Nouveau",
        "url": "/i/p-4-6-5-146_5844_5_1.jpg",
      },
    },
    "quantity": "0",
    "reference": "",
    "stock_status": "0",
    "tax_rate_id": 1,
    "unit": "",
    "updated_at": "2018-06-27T10:43:46Z",
    "weight": 0,   },
```

So I call my photo like this:

> <Image source={{uri:URL+ item.photo.*1*.url}} style={{ width: 25, height: 25}}/>

the constant 'URL' allows me to have the beginning of the url to which to add the end of the url of my array.
Seemed correct to me, I don't understand the error, do you see where the problem is? I will really need to figure out and fix this problem.

Thanks for anyone who will take the time to read my post and help me.

The code of this part :

```
<ListItem
    style={{width:'100%'}}
    containerStyle= {{backgroundColor: item % 2 === 0 ? '#000' : '#ccc'}}
    bottomDivider
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {productId:parseInt(item.id)})}>
    <ListItem.Content style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <Image source={{uri:URL+ item.photo._1_.url}}
             style={{ width: 25, height: 25}}/>
      <ListItem.Title style={{width: '65%', fontSize: 16}}>{ ( item.name.length > 20 ) ? item.name.substring(0, 20) + ' ...'  :  item.name}</ListItem.Title>
      <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400', position: "absolute", bottom: 0, right: 0 }}>{item.cost}€</ListItem.Subtitle>
    </ListItem.Content>
  </ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check this out

```
<Image source={URL+ item.photo["_1_"].url} style={{ width: 25, height: 25}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I did what you suggest,it still returns :
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.photo["_1_"].url')]